# Top and bottom borders on table row

Tags: css, css-tables

How to do this? I want to have different colors on top and bottom borders on the rows in my table. Chrome will render it correct if I use `display: block`, but I don't know if that is the proper way of doing it. However, I want it to work in IE8 and I do not know how.

I've prepared a fiddle that works in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/s6LQ7/

Answer (score 12):

This works on Firefox and IE8:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate; /* Not really necessary unless you use normalize.js */
    border-spacing: 0px; /* take out spaces between cells */
}

tr {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

td {
    width: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #f00; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0f0; /* move spacing to the cell */
}
```

The above uses the standard HTML display systems so that it will work on IE8. I have:

- Set `border-collapse` to `separate`, which prevents the table from collapsing the borders, so it draws each border
- Added `border-spacing` set to `0px` to remove the spacing between cells
- Removed the `display` directives, allowing the table to be displayed as a table
- Moved the `border` directives to the cells, rather than the rows.

http://jsfiddle.net/s6LQ7/1/

Comment: Thank you, but the reason I asked to have the borders on the row element was because my left and right borders on the table cell seem to overlap the top and bottom borders. I need it the other way around. See http://imgur.com/ZH6AAcF

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried putting the border on the cells instead of the rows ?
Plus, most css rules won't apply on table cells unless you use a class as a selector.

Comment: "most css rules won't apply on table cells unless you use a class as a selector" not true. you can style anything on a table using built in tags, you do not need to add classes if you don't want to.